# pictureBox.InvokeRequired not showing img

Tags: c#, image, compact-framework, windows-ce, invoke

I'm receiving from socket communication an `image` as `byte[]` and then I try to show it in a `pictureBox`. When I run the code it shows a message error only saying: `"NullReferenceException"`

The catch handling the exception is `ex1` and I checked and the `pic` isn't `null` so I can't figure it out why this exception is happening.

This is my code:

```
try
{
    if (pictureBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        try
        {
            pic = imageEmp;
            addControlHandler c = new addControlHandler(addPic);
            this.Invoke(c);
        }
        catch (Exception exc) { MessageBox.Show(exc.Message); }
    }
    else
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = ByteToImage(imageEmp);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex1) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex1.Message);                
}

public void addPic()  //when invokeRequired == true
{
    pictureBox1.Image = ByteToImage(pic); 
}
```

Here is the code to convert `byte[]` to `Image`:

```
public Image ByteToImage(byte[] imageBytes)  //convert byte[] to image
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    Image image = new Bitmap(ms); 
    return image;
}
```

**UPDATE 1**: Regarding Hans answer, I make he following changes:

Change my ByteToImage to Hans's answer and to check where the error is I added this lines in the place where `this.Invoke(c)` was:

```
if (c != null)
{
    try
    {
        this.Invoke(c);
    }
    catch (Exception e_c)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e_c.Message, "exc from e_c");
    }
}
```

This give me an exception : `NullReferenceException`

Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE 2:** Now it's working, I send JPEG images instead of JPG and it show it now. Don't know why this happens but now it's working ok.

Comment: Have you tried using a break point ? Where do you get the exception ?

Comment: How confident are you that the entire contents, and just the contents, of the image has been received into your `imageBytes` variable?

Comment: @tcarvin I checked thar by checking imageEmp.Lenght and it's ok

Comment: you don't need a Memory Stream.. also is this a winform or webform based on your answer I can provide you a simple solution

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk I'm not debugging from Visual Studio because when I'm connected to GPRS I can't debugg it I don't know why..

Comment: @DJKRAZE is a winform for CF. The ByteToImage function I'm using it in several parts of my program and it works ok.

Comment: look at my Image pictur = (Image) BrowseForPicture is a Method.. this should work for you if you Cast your Image properly.. try it with your example and let me know if that works for you..

 byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes this will be better and easier to read instead of creating a MemoryStream ... ok

Comment: Do you know which catch is handling the exception? Also displaying ex.message should print out more han just 'exception'. Can you give us the full message?

Comment: I try it with ex.Messagebut it's only displaying "Exception". I don't know why is that

Comment: Can you run with the catches taken out? Don't know what CE displays in this situation, but you should get more info.

Comment: @Surfbutler generally it gives me more info, this is the first time it only shows "Exception"

Comment: This may sound overly simplistic, but have you ensured that pictureBox1 is indeed != null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that you can try I have tested this just now using my own method this works so replace your code with the lines of code in my btnStudentPic_Click let me know if this works for you..

For Compact Framework try this instead

```
public static byte[] ReadAllBytes(string path)
{
byte[] buffer;

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open,
FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
int offset = 0;
int count = (int)fs.Length;
buffer = new byte[count];
while (count > 0)
{
int bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, offset, count);
offset += bytesRead;
count -= bytesRead;
}
}

return buffer;
}
```

//Windows example below don't use for CF

```
    private void btnStudentPic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image picture = (Image)BrowseForPicture();
        this.picStudent.Image = picture;
        this.picStudent.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Bitmap BrowseForPicture()
    {
       // Bitmap picture = null;

        try
        {
            if (this.fdlgStudentPic.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(this.fdlgStudentPic.FileName);
                StudentPic = new Bitmap( this.fdlgStudentPic.FileName);
                StuInfo.StudentPic = imageBytes;
            }
            else
            {
                StudentPic = Properties.Resources.NoPhotoAvailable;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("That was not a picture.", "Browse for picture");
            StudentPic = this.BrowseForPicture();
        }

        return StudentPic;
    }
```

Comment: since I'm using the code in CompactFramework I can't use, for instance, the File.ReadAllBytes. That's why I'm using my ByteToImage function, which so far is working fine.